# building GCC on ARM: undefined reference to `ggc_alloc_zone_vec_rtvec_def'

Tags: gcc, arm, gcc4

I'm trying to compile GCC on synology DS109 NAS disk which is powered by Marvell Kirkwood mv6281 ARM Processor.

It is currently running quite outdated GCC 4.2.3 which is the newest vesion that I found for it in binaries.

I tried GCC 4.7.1 and 4.6.3 both with same result during `make` phase:

```
    build/genflags.o build/rtl.o build/read-rtl.o build/ggc-none.o build/vec.o 
build/min-insn-modes.o build/gensupport.o build/print-rtl.o build/read-md.o 
build/errors.o ../build-armv5tel-unknown-linux-gnueabi/libiberty/libiberty.a
build/rtl.o: In function `rtvec_alloc':
/volume1/public/gcc-4.6.3/build/gcc/../../gcc-4.6.3/gcc/rtl.c:153: undefined reference 
to `ggc_alloc_zone_vec_rtvec_def'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [build/genflags] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/volume1/public/gcc-4.6.3/build/gcc'
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/volume1/public/gcc-4.6.3/build'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/volume1/public/gcc-4.6.3/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

configure was runed normally complaining only about missing `tr` but not giving any error.

I'm building dependecies (gmp & comp.) also with gcc using vesions downloaded by download_prerequisities script which is comming with GCC.

I also tried v4.5.4 with no luck but different error message:

```
gcc -c  -g -fkeep-inline-functions -DIN_GCC   -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wc++-compat -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../../gcc-4.5.4/gcc -I../../gcc-4.5.4/gcc/. -I../../gcc-4.5.4/gcc/../include -I../../gcc-4.5.4/gcc/../libcpp/include -I/volume1/public/gcc-4.5.4/build/./gmp -I/volume1/public/gcc-4.5.4/gcc-4.5.4/gmp -I/volume1/public/gcc-4.5.4/build/./mpfr -I/volume1/public/gcc-4.5.4/gcc-4.5.4/mpfr -I/volume1/public/gcc-4.5.4/gcc-4.5.4/mpc/src  -I../../gcc-4.5.4/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc-4.5.4/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber     ../../gcc-4.5.4/gcc/c-lang.c -o c-lang.o
../../gcc-4.5.4/gcc/c-lang.c:58:21: error: gtype-c.h: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [c-lang.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/volume1/public/gcc-4.5.4/build/gcc'
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/volume1/public/gcc-4.5.4/build'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/volume1/public/gcc-4.5.4/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone please give me any clue what I should try out?